# Incrase PHP memory limit will my site load faster ? (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

If l increase PHP memory limit will my site load faster ?

l use cloud server 6gb ram , current PHP memory limit setting = 512mb

How much should l setting for best performance ?

Thank you.

Comment: Too broad, and dependent on loads of factors that only you can collate. The answer to your initial question is, "maybe".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the more the better for PHP memory\_limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858457/is-the-more-the-better-for-php-memory-limit)

Comment: Possible, but most likely that will _not_ be the case. For typical web applications the memory footprint is not the limiting factor. Only of intensive computations like graphics manipulations are done, then this might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that depends for the site to load faster?

Web servers are just like any other computer. They need memory to efficiently run multiple applications at the same time. Server administrators allocate specific memory size to different applications including PHP. 
PHP memory limit can be stated as RAM in the computer device..

Reference site: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/fix-wordpress-memory-exhausted-error-increase-php-memory/

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, no, it's a good answer. Memory limit sets how many memory can you use in an execution of a single script after being blocked.

In a very low case, if the script is prepared to be executed, for example, 10 times to process 100 tasks, but you can parametrize to do 100 tasks in a single execution the performance will be incremented.

The recommended memory_limit value is related with your application and its limited by the physical (or virtual) memory on your machine, but you can't define in base of that.